# How to handle grep in a txt file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

As a newbie in bash shell scripting I am trying to figure out how to handle 3 different situations with grep. In that script I have two parameters(one txt file , one variable). 
In that script I need to:

1)find and show the number of each line which starting with the given variable

2)find and show the number of each line which contains the given variable

3)find and show the number of each line which ends with the given variable

Text details:

```
unix is great os. unix is opensource. unix is free os.
learn operating system.
Unix linux which one you choose.
uNix is easy to learn.unix is a multiuser os.Learn unix .unix is a powerful.
```

Written script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Give a string."
read variable
file="/home/mikepnrs/data.txt"

grep -n "^$variable" $file
echo "Lines starting with: $variable" grep -c "^$variable" $file
grep -n "$variable" $file
echo "Lines containing : $variable" grep '$[variable]*$' file
grep -n "$variable$" $file
echo "Lines ending with : $variable" grep -c "$variable$" file
```

Given "un" as an argument in variable I'm having the following results. The first answer seems to work fine but I can't understand what am I doing wrong for the rest.

```
1:unix is great os. unix is opensource. unix is free os.
Lines starting with : un grep -c ^un /home/mikepnrs/data.txt                                                                                                                                                                               
1:unix is great os. unix is opensource. unix is free os.
4:uNix is easy to learn.unix is a multiuser os.Learn unix .unix is a powerful.
Lines containing : un grep $[variable]*$ file
Lines ending with : un grep -c un$ file
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You missed the _pipes_ between echo and grep: `echo x | grep x`

Comment: I'm not sure how the output you show is unexpected. Only the first line starts with `un`, the first and fourth contain `un`, and no line ends with `un`. Remember matching is case sensitive by default - if you wanted case-insensitive, you'd have needed `grep -i`. What output did you expect?

Comment: Also, I notice the commands shown under `echo` are different from the ones you actually run, which are correct for this problem, while the ones in `echo` are not.